# -phonegap- Icomatic Topcoat icons render in Chrome but not in Android

Tags: android, cordova, topcoat

I'm trying to make a custom button with an icon on it using Phonegap.

I used https://github.com/topcoat/icons, and www.icomatic.io to create the icons.
Then I saved the resulting icomatic files in a www/css/icomatic folder.

For some reason the following code works(shows the icon) in my normal (chrome) webbrowser, but not on my phone (it just displays the button with the word camera):

```
<button class="topcoat-icon-button" id="takePicture">
    <span class="topcoat-icon icomatic">camera</span>
</button>
```

I use the icomatic.css in the wwww/css/icomatic.css folder. The css is:

```
src: url('icomatic.eot');
src: url('icomatic.eot?#iefix') format("embedded-opentype"),
     url('icomatic.woff') format("woff"),
     url('icomatic.ttf') format("truetype"),
     url('icomatic.svg#icomatic') format('svg');
```

referenced like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/icomatic/icomatic.css"/>
```

Thanks!

//EDIT:
It seems this issue is occuring specifically on certain device/software(Android 4.3, Xperia Z)

On another android device I tried, the camera icon showed up normally..

Comment: can you provide the css for the icon? It is possibly a pathing issue.

Comment: as far as I can see all the css is generated by icomatic, i have no extra css..

Comment: What I am getting at is, how is the file referenced in the css? Android is very specific on how you path to files within JS and CSS, so maybe the path setting to the file is not compatible for android. you may need to alter the path to get it to display.

Comment: I edited the question. do you mean this?

Comment: Yes, thank you. So from this it looks like the `icomatic.*` files should be in `css/icomatic` with the icomatic.css file, is this true?

Comment: Was this present on 4.4 on the same device?

Comment: there is no official v4.4 yet for this device (will be released this month though)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the top of the icomatic.css file, when I changed the font-face definition to use the SVG format first, it fixed the problem.  I'm guessing the EOT type font isn't fully supported on Android 4.3 yet.

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'Icomatic';
src: url('icomatic.svg#icomatic') format('svg');
src: url('icomatic.eot?#iefix') format("embedded-opentype"),
     url('icomatic.woff') format("woff"),
     url('icomatic.ttf') format("truetype"),
     url('icomatic.svg#icomatic') format('svg');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Then I read the FAQ that Icomatic document, accessible at the bottom of the icomatic.html file that comes with your icomatic's fonts in the Zip. They mention that the Javascript script icomatic.js offers a fallback to browsers that don't support fully @font-face and ligature.

So you should add to your existing configuration already mentionned in your html page:

```
<head>
...    
<script src="ico/icomatic.js"></script>
<script>
    window.onload = function() { IcomaticUtils.run(); }
</script>
...
</head>
```

For one page, this fallback didn't works, so I had a the end of my html page before :

```
<script>
    IcomaticUtils.run();
</script>
```

Now I have my icomatic icons collection working on Android Kitkat and Jelly Bean. Icomatic mention that they support even Android 1+, let say CupCake ! and iOS 3+.